# is there some easy way of editing last row data from form (php)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

my goal is to build a form that will update a row (automatically updates the last row)
what i have in hand write now is this see picture below
it just adds new row instead of editing last available one

**Screenshot:**
[image]

it updates contact (just adds new ones instead of updating the last column) column but i want to update the last one ex id 3
the rest is just being added not updated
thank you.\
I am happy to clarify more.

***edit:*** here is the form and code `(password = null)`
[image]

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
if (!empty($contact)){
    if (!empty($password)){
        $host = "localhost";
        $dbusername = "root";
        $dbpassword = "";
        $dbname = "student";
// Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
        
        if (mysqli_connect_error()){
            die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno() .') '
                . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO student_table2 (contact)
    values ('$contact')";
            if ($conn->query($sql)){
                header("Location: http://localhost/imgtxt/add/add.html");
                exit();
            }
        }
    
    else {
            echo "Error: ". $sql ."
        ". $conn->error;
        }
    $conn->close();
    }
    else {
        echo "Password should not be empty";
        die();
    }
    }
    else {
        echo "contact should not be empty";
        die();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverGnome. Please **edit your question** to **show your code**; principly your PHP and your MySQL insert/update code.

Comment: This is gonna be a trip, we're 2 people with the same name. Anyways, you can simply update `where id = (select max(id) from table)`. Assuming you're using auto incremented ID values, of course. But I can't help to think that this comes off as a "hack" to an actual architectural problem that you might wanna look at instead. A proper flow should never be like this.

Comment: As correctly pointed out by @Martin you are needing to do an `UPDATE` rather than an `INSERT` . But you are only showing an INSERT SQL code. As an alternative/ extension of this concept you can also do a [DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540270/mysql-update-with-on-duplicate-key-update) and supply a key value (the ID)

Comment: You should never output errors to screen, you should be recording them in your PHP Error logs.

Comment: And your code brackets are a mess. You have syntax errors in your code. Your brackets don't match up. Your life will be +4 better when you add comments to the closing brackets so you know WHAT is being closed.... `} // close if error found` etc.

Comment: @Martin exactly, you're amazing!

Comment: alright 
but how about the automatically updating the last row ?